# Check if one GameObject is placed on top of another in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two cubes with one being slightly bigger than the other and can be moved around freely around the scene by the user.

I need to know **when the user has placed the smaller one on top of the bigger one** and then continue with the script.

I understand that I need to check the collision somehow and maybe check the Y coordinate of both boxes too to make sure the user puts the smaller cube on top of the bigger and not vice versa.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could either create a trigger (more on that in the unity docs) and use the respecrive callback to continue or you could constantly check the position of the second object and if the coordinates are above  the ones of the big box continue.

Comment: I thought about checking the position of the second object at first, but this would be true if the user just holds the object over the other one without actually placing it on top of it.

Comment: Just check for mouse release too

Comment: learn to use triggers and do it that way. you will have to master **layers** in Unity also.